# A good packet proccessing Java library for PostgreSQL packets?

Tags: postgresql, networking, jdbc

I should develop a simple server side proxy to PostgreSQL database.The proxy should sniff the queries and block them or let them go and also send back the database response to user( in reality the upper client JDBC driver).
I want to know is there any good library in Java in order to process packets(or even better SQL packets)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you want this? Is there anything specific you want to restrict, that cannot be accomplished by restrictive GRANTs/REVOKEs ?

Comment: that is and intrusion detection system that validate queries to be sql injection free .

Comment: You're dong it wrong. Instead of sanitising your input, you should use prepared statements only. And maybe you don't need "naked" SQL access for the client/front-end.

Comment: the problem is that we have not access client code.we just can configure its connection port , etc from a file so using prepared statement is not possible.

Comment: You cannot in principle 'validate queries to be SQL injection free'. By the time you see them any SQL injection has already happened. Rethink.

Comment: Sql injection happens when a wrong query pass to database actually we want to set a layer above that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to process "packets" at all. You want to process the PostgreSQL protocol, which is an exchange of *messages*. These messages are carried over TCP/IP in packets, but you shouldn't be dealing with them at that level if you're writing a proxy.

The only PostgreSQL protocol implementation I'm aware of is part of PgJDBC, and is client-side only. It's also not very generalized.

You will have to write your own using [the PostgreSQL protocol documentation for reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html). You will find Wireshark's support for dissecting the PostgreSQL protocol very helpful while doing so.

Of course, it sounds like you then want to *parse the SQL* and make decisions based on the content of the SQL. That would require an SQL parser that understands PostgreSQL's dialect. The only one I'm aware of is the PostgreSQL server's parser, and it's not something you can just separate out and plug into another app, let alone Java code. PgPool-II also contains a very limited parser, but again it's in C and not written as a separate library. Again, you're going to have to write your own.

Implementing the prococol is easy, but implementing a parser and then reasoning about the SQL using the parse tree results is *very* hard. Don't go there.

If you insist on pursuing this approach you should at minimum start by modifying PgPool-II or  PgBouncer, instead of writing your own proxy from scratch.

A superior approach in my opinion would be to implement a PostgreSQL extension that installs a  `planner_hook` or `post_parse_analyze_hook` to try to detect whatever problem you're having and `ERROR` on those queries. Or modify the core code directly (creating a custom PostgreSQL build) if you can't do what you need to with a hook.

Overall it'd be a *lot* more sensible to avoid the need for this in the first place by fixing any client applications. Especially as the whole concept of "validating" SQL to ensure it's "SQL injection free" is bunk. You can potentially detect *simple and obvious* attempts at SQL injection this way, reject multi-statements and statements ending in comments, etc, but generalized detection of SQL injection attacks as distinct from legitimate queries isn't really possible. If it was, *database servers would already implement it*.

Comment: thank you for your detailed and helpful answer.actually we have the parser now(that is part of a M.Sc thesis) We just need a place to put the code that I think the first part of your answer cover our problem nice.thanks again

Comment: How about functions: `delete from user where uppercase(username) <> lowercase(username);` ? And how about user-defined functions, or data types ?

Comment: @wildplasser Exactly. The whole concept is futile. Fix the problem app or replace it. That said, such a proxy *might* mitigate casual SQL injection attacks/scanning by a non-determined attacker.

Comment: I also think that the parse tree is *nothing* before it has been *decorated* by info from the catalogs. Which will need access to the DB, and cannot be implemented as a standalone filter inbetween client & server. BTW: one of the nasty details in this is the `search_path` for schamas...

Comment: @wildplasser Again, that really limits the possibilities - but you can still detect really obvious stuff like `');STATEMENT;--` - at the risk of rejecting legitimate multi-statements in the process.

Comment: We don't say that all injections will be detected .That is a hot topic in research(you can find a lot of papers on IEEE in this area). Briefly the algorithm is that we remove datas in '' in other words 'blah blha' will convert to '  ' and also numbers that is not concat to a string such as (4,5,'third'); or salary=salary+10 and .. and also booleans will be removed.then learn the digested query.for every new query in deployment phase do the same and compare them with learned queries.@wildplasser your suggested query also will be detected easily this way(feel free to ask me about more details)